# Hiding table header if table rows until next table header are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list in a table that is alphabetically ordered like so.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th><strong>A</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-me">Ants</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-me">Animals</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td  class="hide-me">Apples</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><strong>B</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bars</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-me">Bats</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-me">Bananas</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><strong>C</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cans</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cars</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cats</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I use the `$('table tr:has(td.hide-me)').hide()` method to hide any of the elements that I don't want shown. However I also want to be able to hide the table headers if the table rows that contain normal table cells are hidden.

In the case above I would like to hide `<tr><th><strong>A</strong></th></tr>` because it has all of the following table rows hidden but not the  the `<tr><th><strong>B</strong></th></tr>` because not all of the table rows are hidden.

I am relatively new to Jquery and am not sure how best implement conditional statements for a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was put a class on the `tr` to indicate that that row contained a header.  This makes it much easier to tell which rows are headers, rather than having to interrogate if they contain a `th`.

The second thing I did was change your hide expression for the `.hide-me` to find the hide me first, then find their parent trs, and hide them.  This way the selector doesn't have to find the tr and check if each one has a hide me.

Then finally the logic finds all the headers, and shows them, so if any were previously hidden, they would be visible.  It then filters the headers and only returns the ones that do not have any following trs that are not hidden.  Havin the headers that do not have any visible following trs, it then hides them.

```js
$('.hide-me').closest('tr').hide();

$('.header').show().filter(function(){
  return $(this).nextUntil('.header').filter(':not(:hidden)').length < 1;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <th><strong>A</strong></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide-me">Ants</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide-me">Animals</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide-me">Apples</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="header">
      <th><strong>B</strong></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bars</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide-me">Bats</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide-me">Bananas</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="header">
      <th><strong>C</strong></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cans</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cars</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cats</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```